# Using ServiceStack and RabbitMQ to send a stream

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, streaming, servicestack, amqp

I am attempting to send a stream using RabbitMQ and Servicestack (v1.0.41 using .NET Core).

My Request implements `ServiceStack.Web.IRequiresRequestStream`, and the stream property is set in the client, but when it gets to the server, the stream is `NULL`.

**Complete Repo**
Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Funq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Messaging;
using ServiceStack.RabbitMq;
using ServiceStack.Web;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseServer(new RabbitServer())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public class RabbitServer : IServer
    {
        public void Dispose(){}

        public void Start<TContext>(IHttpApplication<TContext> application){}

        public IFeatureCollection Features { get; } = new FeatureCollection();
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseServiceStack((AppHostBase)Activator.CreateInstance<AppHost>());
            app.Run((RequestDelegate)(context => (Task)Task.FromResult<int>(0)));
        }

    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost()
            : base("My Test Service", typeof(MyService).GetAssembly())
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var mqServer = new RabbitMqServer("127.0.0.1");
            container.Register<IMessageService>(mqServer);
            mqServer.RegisterHandler<HelloRequest>(ExecuteMessage);
            mqServer.Start();
        }
    }

    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public HelloResponse Any(HelloRequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Stream is null: {request.RequestStream == null}");
            return new HelloResponse { Counter = request.Counter };

        }
    }

    public class HelloRequest : IReturn<HelloResponse>, IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }

        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Messaging;
using ServiceStack.RabbitMq;
using ServiceStack.Web;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RabbitMqServer messageService = new RabbitMqServer("127.0.0.1");
            RabbitMqQueueClient mqClient = messageService.MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient() as RabbitMqQueueClient;
            var responseQueueName = mqClient.GetTempQueueName();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!")) { Position = 0 };
            HelloRequest request = new HelloRequest { Counter = 100, RequestStream = ms };  //Counter is just some arbitary extra data
            Guid messageId = Guid.NewGuid();

            mqClient.Publish(QueueNames<HelloRequest>.In, new Message<HelloRequest>(request) { ReplyTo = responseQueueName, Id = messageId });
        }
    }

    public class HelloRequest : IReturn<HelloResponse>, IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note: I realise I could just use a byte[] in my request object, but I would quite like to make use of the provided `IRequiresRequestStream` interface so I can switch back to using HTTP rather than AMQP in the future.

I should also say, that I probably won't be using the RabbitMQ Client provided by servicestack, as I am writing custom logic to convert from HTTP to AMQP, so I will be building the rabbitMQ request manually - the code above just demonstrates the problem I am having in the simplest way possible.

I'm going to assume that this won't just work out of the box with AMQP (as it does with HTTP) - so I was thinking that I need to do something like serialize the stream to a `byte[]` and include it in the RabbitMQ message and then populate the dto which ServiceStack magically re-hydrates on the Server.

So two questions really...
1. Am I on the right track?
2. If so, how do I hook into the de-serialization code on the server so that I have access to the raw RabbitMQ message in order to convert my byte[] back to a stream and set the stream on my dto?

Comment: Added extra info about my use case

Comment: But conceptually you cannot send stream via rabbit, because "sending" just puts a message into queue, from which server consumes those messages.

Comment: @Evk Yes, I know that - but ServiceStack takes care of alot of these sort of problems for you, adding a layer of abstraction between the service communication and the transport... having said that - in this case it doesn't, which is why I was asking if sending a byte[] in the queue message is the way to handle the scenario, or if there is something else ServiceStack does that can take care of it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send a `IRequiresRequestStream` Request DTO into a MQ because it's not a normal serialized Request DTO, instead it instructs ServiceStack to skip deserializing the Request DTO and instead inject the HTTP Request Stream so the Service can perform its own Deserialization instead, this is different to a normal Request DTO which is serialized and can be sent as the body in an MQ Message.

One option if you want to share implementation between a `IRequiresRequestStream` Service and a Service that can be called by MQ is to just delegate to a common Service that accepts bytes, e.g:

```
//Called from HTTP
public object Any(HelloStream request) => 
    Any(new HelloBytes { Bytes = request.RequestStream.ReadFully() });

//Called from HTTP or MQ
public object Any(HelloBytes request) 
{
    //= request.Bytes
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's kinda what I was thinking. `...this is different to a normal Request DTO which is serialized and can be sent as the body in an MQ Message.` - does that mean that ServiceStack has some sort of functionality to send the stream as the body of the MQ message in place of the DTO, or is that something I need to code for myself?
I was tinkering with this last night, and I now have a dto base class which both implements `IRequiresRequestStream` and provides a property for a `byte[]` with a method called `GetBytes()` which returns either a byte array ...[contd]

Comment: ... so my http request (that I convert to AMQP) still has the standard `RequestStream` property from the interface and my code which does the conversion (from HTTP to AMQP) will read in bytes from the stream and populate the `byte[]` property on the dto. My service methods now feature requests which implement this base class, and the service code always calls `GetBytes()`, so now I think I can dump AMQP in the future if it doesn't suit. Unless SS does something like this, I can't think of a better way of sending streamed content across the wire using SS and AMQP.

Comment: @Jay All ServiceStack is doing with `IRequiresRequestStream` is not attempting to deserialize it and populate the `ReqeustStream` property with HTTP Request Body Input Stream instead. There is no streaming messages in MQ's, the entire message needs to be sent in the MQ body. I've updated my answer with a potential solution if you want to share the same impl, otherwise just have 2 services if you want the HTTP impl to do something different.

Comment: Ok, thats cool (I do understand that you can't stream in MQ btw!) and so now I know that this is a problem I need to solve for myself using the code I described above, or another service method as you suggested to move the stream content as the body of a MQ message. Thanks for your time!